# Why is somebody editing my questions?

Tags: discussion

I don't post many questions, but the few that I have --- somebody is coming in and making VERY MINOR edits.

I mean like picayune grammatical or punctuation changes.  Trivial stuff.  Example -- I put 3 "???" at the end of sentence, for dramatic effect I guess.  Big deal.   This was edited to a single "?".    Seriously????   WHY????????????????    Is the server charging by the byte these days?

Frankly - it's SUPER INSULTING that my words are being changed.  I write what I write with *intent*.  I proofread several times to make sure things are clear and understandable.  I am not a bad speller, and I don't have poor grammar.  Nothing that was edited does diddly to improve intelligibility.  This is like the editor saying "I'm better spoken than you".  Either that, or he/she is a closet English professor.

I realize this message will probably be deleted, or 'thumbed' down a million times.  That's OK

EDIT

Some great points given - Thank you.  And yes, this belonged in EE META.  I'll admit now, I didn't realize 'EE meta' existed... I only ever saw Meta for the whole SE site (and I didn't think anywhere near right for 'whole site').  I did not know there was a Meta for EE only.

Also quickly - I've had this happen more than twice as suggested.  I had to think about that for a bit, but I recall now I was so off-put by the arcaneness of the edits I'd been subjected to before I rolled them back a couple times.  Heck, my post earlier today was edited *twice*... that's what I wrote this!

I guess my problem is I'M HUMAN and I want to converse with humans.  Every single question & every single answer here is written & read by humans, so why are we writing like bots?  I reply to questions because I like helping people.
I imagine *everybody* who contributes here does the same. Why else would you?
The prose does not need to be parsed to machine-readable form for that.

Thx for the passive-aggressive insults in the comments. Not gonna lie, I drank way too much coffee today and I deserved it #thumbsup  I edited out a bit of my own original passive aggressiveness

Thx more to the folks who chose not to #2thumbsup

Comment: This question belongs in meta, not the main namespace. Though arguably it doesn't even belong there, as this is more of a rant than a question. No one editing your questions is doing so with any ill intent.

Comment: Also, out of all the questions you've posted, I see exactly two that have been edited by anyone other than you. I think you're blowing this entirely out of proportion.

Comment: @Hearth I know that there's no ill intent.  It's a non-intentional insult - That's why it bugs me.  If it were editing incorrect numbers or equations, absolutely it should be done.  But what I'm seeing is akin to me painting my door blue, then the editor comes down the road, decides doesn't like that blue and paints it a different shade of blue.  Is it only 2?   Well maybe, still -- Those were unnecessary.

Comment: No, it's more like someone copyediting something you wrote on a wikipedia article. This site's purpose is to produce a corpus of questions and answers that future people with the same question can come find and find answers to--so it's important that the questions and answers be as clear as possible. And yes, it's only two, and one of them someone only edited the tags.

Comment: @Kyle B - Welcome to StackExchange :-/     I've had similar moments and similar sentiments. Not everyone agrees on style. You can always reverse the edit and leave a comment to the editor. After some thought, I concluded that the mods and the more active senior users do quite a bit of thankless work to keep the various forms of crap in check, so it's an okay compromise for the most part

Comment: Don't sweat it , I use grammarly and still make grammar errors,  
 I wish more people would add to my content. and correct my dumb errors: double prepositions and missing participles.  If it helps , cite a specific example in the META forum, otherwise not here , it's a misplaced concern. I wouldn't worry about a different shade of blue door. But a pink door just wouldn't match my decor, except for my Red Touque. Besides, we should try to impress our ESL visitors with our eloquent  mastery of language.

Comment: @pipe suppositively just caffeine if you check the edits

Comment: Remember that not all of our readers are native English speakers. Using words like "Thx", "gonna", "diddly", and "hookie" are vague and can be confusing. I won't hesitate to edit that kind of language.

Comment: "*WHY????????????????*" Because that's not good writing of English.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah this is a question for ee meta stack exchange and as such does not deserve an answer here.  It should be transferred there or deleted.  That said my answer will be written in such a way as to be fine on the meta.  This is written to give perspective on why we don't make this type of pride a factor in the curation of the site.

The site benefits from better technical communication, as do both the editors and readers.  The site is built so as to crowdsource editorial duties and helping improve questions, whether in a minor or major way is one of the few ways new users can build the initial points they need to really start participating.  Not every edit is even beneficial, but the system is built so as to easily reverse or correct bad edits.  This means more edits and more participation inevitably bring us to a better condition and thus are to be encouraged, even if they are very minor(who cares) or wrong(an actual problem but easily corrected).  One caveat I would note is that there is a minimum character limit on edits meant to discourage pithy editing, but in EE, some small edits are so important that a person is forced to make the necessary correction and add an unnecessary rephrasing elsewhere to get the actual important edit corrected.

I'm an Electrician rather than an engineer, so the subset of questions I can gain those initial points by answering is small, but I have excellent English and decent technical communications skills, so there is a massive variety of questions I can improve for the engineers.  I really like this site and it adds significant value to my life even if I didn't finish engineering school.  We're incredibly lucky that these engineers show up to offer their hard earned expertise with huge patience and very little complaint(Proactive correction is a valid part of education and does not count as complaint).  Note that those of us who have been around for a while know the "vibes" of what makes people want to answer a question and therefore what kind of writing turns off talented contributors.

It's in my interest to make this as much as possible an enjoyable place for the engineers to be, and for users like me, making even minor improvements to make a question more clear, concise, readable, or make it conform to the site rules.  This means when an engineer gets there, they waste less time on spelling, grammar, logic, clarity, etc. and they can direct their efforts to the actual electrical engineering, maximizing their not easily replacable contribution.

One other thing you'll notice if you spend time around here is there's not enough volunteer to go around, and as a result not everyone even has time for truly minor corrections.  For example, there's a lot wrong with your question as you've written it.  I could hit the edit button and improve it as normally would be done, but I'll include it here instead with background on why each edit is necessary or just ideal.

> I don't post many questions, but the few that I have --- somebody is
> coming in and making VERY MINOR edits.

This is more acceptable on meta, and includes a large mass of extraneous information, which is against the rules here on EE.  All you should include is the relevant information, without dramatization(also forbidden), and it's also likely a variety of people, so "People have been making very minor edits to my questions."

> I mean like picayune grammatical or punctuation changes. Trivial
> stuff. Example -- I put 3 "???" at the end of sentence, for dramatic
> effect I guess. Big deal. This was edited to a single "?".
> Seriously???? WHY???????????????? Is the server charging by the byte
> these days???

This is a recursive example of the same problem.  The correction in question is over unnecessary dramatization, and you have unnecessarily dramatized asking about it out of spite.  The second question in this paragraph is sarcastic and rhetorical(also forbidden), but there is actually a somewhat relevant core so I'll still include it.  This should have been written "For example why would someone bother correcting extra punctuation(a triple question mark) in one of my questions?  Are shorter responses favored in some way?".  The answer to the first question is in the site rules, the answer to the second question is yes.  Usually the word "concise" is used to describe a statement that is short in an optimal way.  It's favorable for writing to be as concise as possible without affecting clarity, although this usually applies more to structure and grammar than punctuation.

> Frankly - it's SUPER INSULTING that my words are being changed. I
> write what I write with intent. I proofread several times to make sure
> things are clear and understandable. I am not a bad speller, and I
> don't have poor grammar. Nothing that was edited does diddly to
> improve intelligibility. This is like the editor saying "I'm better
> spoken than you". Either that, or he/she is a closet English
> professor.

The problems with melodramatic capitalization have been covered.  Here you should say "I feel insulted" rather than "It's" as obviously this is not universal or common to feel in this context.  This is a clarity problem(fallacy) and in the next sentence you say that you already checked to make sure your writing is clear and understandable.  These two sentences are together an argument for an editing process with many eyes.  You go on to follow an imperfectly structured sentence(should be in the affirmative), with a double negative(decreases intelligibility) in a sentence about intelligibility.  As far as the rest I personally make corrections because better is better(unnecessary truism in my own writing) and I care about the quality of the site.  I don't care whether I'm better or worse at English any more than I feel bad about the masses of knowledge these engineers have(including English skills in some cases) that I don't.  You also use "closet English professor" like an insult, which again is forbidden(unnecessary dramatization, extraneous information) and also kind of silly since skill is skill.  English is a general skill you apply to Engineering rather than a strictly necessary core skill, but it still has value.

Because it's a large paragraph:  A better way to write it would be:

"I find it insulting when my words are changed.  I write with intent and do my best to proofread.  I have good spelling and grammar.  I don't believe these edits improve intelligibility.  I feel like editors are saying that they are better spoken than me.

> I realize this message will probably be deleted, or 'thumbed' down a
> million times. Don't care. Fire me, not getting paid here anyhow. I
> have plenty other things I can burn my time on, plenty other sites I
> post at that appreciate my 25 years engineering experience and welcome
> the valuable advice I freely share without "correcting" my grammar or
> punctuation.

As above, if this question is deleted it's because it has little to do with EE, and rather is about EE Stack Exchange and therefore should be on EE meta.  We don't edit or delete things to punish people or make them feel bad, so the way you've phrased this isn't great.  Interestingly at the very end you reveal that you are actually one of the prized engineer contributors.  If you decide to stick around, hello and welcome!  If not I hope you find a website that runs the way you like it to.  I think you might prefer one that operates as a forum or message board rather than this one, which is built as a living document with the specific goal of producing high quality in both question and answer.  To get an idea, read the tour and background information for the site.  There are probably other rules you aren't aware of and may not like, and once you know how the site is intended to work and why you might either be less offended or you might not see it as a place you'll enjoy.

Just noticed I forgot to paraphrase the last paragraph.  I'll include that here:

"I realize this question will probably be deleted or get a million downvotes.  I feel like my 25 years of engineering experience would be valuable to the site, but I find being corrected strongly discourages me from posting here. I may not continue posting here if people continue to correct my spelling and grammar."

When we see something that can be improved and we feel up to it, we improve it.  In reality you'll find you can actually get away with a lot.  What I've written here will probably pass muster, but even aside from the flaws in my writing I pointed out, there are others I was aware of while writing.  I don't get edited often, but anyone who wants can come along and improve what I've written here, and as long as they don't remove core concepts or decrease clarity, I won't retract their edit.  Why should I want to?  Better is better.

Comment: Thank you brother.  Your candor is truly appreciated. I understand the reason for the dryness of the site, and I've played along.  And I know the mods work hard for basically nothing - which is why I'm so perplexed as to the reason folks would burn time making the edits to my posts that they do.   I told a joke once, went over like a f*rt in church.  You may be right, I may belong elsewhere.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned you're welcome here, but I hope you stop feeling anything bad about edits.  If I edit your writing, just think of me as your secretary or brand new EIT.  You have to check my work because I might misinterpret a technical term or some such, but on average the engineer gets to rubber stamp and send out better documents with very little effort put into things outside their purview.

Comment: Sneaking a joke in is one of the finest challenges of the site, as the joke itself must be technically relevant.  I recently used "Apples to Aardvarks" in place of "Apples to Oranges", which is technically a joke, but makes the point that the items are even less comparable than different items within the same category.  It's possible, but it isn't easy.

Comment: As for jokes, I have put a few, and when clearly labelled as a joke in a comment they can get several upvotes - especially when the joke is about the core issue at hand. Nothing wrong with a relevant joke as long as it is tasteful...

Comment: Tip: There should always be a space before a "(" in normal text writing. :^)

Comment: @Transistor Thanks all better.

Answer (score 13):

I think this section of your edited question explains the root of the problem you're having:

> I guess my problem is I'M HUMAN and I want to converse with humans. Every single question & every single answer here is written & read by humans, so why are we writing like bots? I reply to questions because I like helping people. I imagine everybody who contributes here does the same. Why else would you? The prose does not need to be parsed to machine-readable form for that.

This is actually wrong. Stack Exchange was *designed* to be parsed by search engine robots. You are *not* writing an answer to the single person asking the question. You are writing an answer to the hundreds of people trying to search for solutions to the same problem.

If you want discussions with humans, there are hundreds of other more traditional forums. Maybe you would be happier there.

Comment: Yes +1 ... I think this insight helps explain some of the StackExchange peculiarities. As with nearly all other modern sites, it has naturally evolved / optimized to produce max search rank

Comment: @PeteW More like optimized to put good answers on top of bad answers, instead of giving you a massive forum thread where everyone has to chime in with their bad advice and off-topic ramblings.

Comment: That's part of it, and I like that part. But the flip side is it rewards cookie-cutter q&a form, well-posed questions about how to hook up an Arduino to a Relay, etc, while the open-ended discussions that can be very fruitful get thrown out, baby with the bathwater and all. Your point that they would belong better in a traditional forum is totally valid

Answer (score 9):

Stack Exchange encourages editing, there are a few badges that encourage this behavior and is welcome as long as it is improving the post. Secondly they are not really "your posts" once you post they are released under the creative commons license. Also you should use standard grammar and understand that technical speech is likely to be the norm here. Text speech is not as welcome, please don't use it

Answer (score 8):

It sounds like you are asking about my first of two [edits to your recent question about EEPROM fatigue](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/552140/revisions). In both of my edits I removed the "Thx" at the end (as well as the extra "?" marks) since it is a well-established consensus on the SE network that [posts should not include "thanks" or similar extraneous text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/299342) (similarly, "EDIT" notes in your post are not necessary nor desirable since the edit history is logged).

I thought your question was an interesting one so I upvoted it, and it has since made the hot network questions list. It looks like it will serve as a useful Q&A for many users in the years to come. However, it was marred by the unnecessary (and, in the case of the "thanks", misspelled) text. For the sake of everyone who reads that question I edited it to conform to the established SE formatting guidelines.